# preprocessing images for svm model in python

Tags: python, machine-learning, svm

I am a beginner in machine learning and I'm trying to make an SVM image classifier using python.
I have my own dataset of images. I have done the following steps:
1) created different folders for each class(binary class)
2) Imported all the images into my jupyter notebook.

Now I am having an issue while creating a proper dataset that can be fed into the SVM model.
I tried to append the image array and its class into a list called dataset. But now I am unable to flatten the images as a vector.

Please tell me if my steps are right?
If right, then what should I do to flatten the images properly.

```
#path to the base dir
base_dir = "/home/khyati/projects/plant_project/try/dataset"

#path of various folders
apple_path = os.path.join(base_dir, "Apple___Apple_scab")
tomato_path = os.path.join(base_dir, "Tomato___Late_blight")

#list of available labels
classes = ["Apple___Apple_scab", "Tomato___Late_blight"]

dataset = []
for category in classes:
    path = os.path.join(base_dir, category)
    for img in os.listdir(path):
        #`enter code here`print(img)
        image = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path,img))
        label =classes.index(category)
        dataset.append([image,label])
print(dataset[1])
```

I want this data to be in the form which can be fed into the classification model.

Comment: Use numpy. You can call `numpy.flatten` or `numpy.ravel` to flatten the images. And from machine learning point of view, CNNs perform better on images. If you don't have to use SVM, I recommend you use a CNN

Comment: @SohaibJundi how can i pass the flattened image to SVM? my code is pretty much similar to his, i guess we watched the same tutorial, please explain

Answer (score 0):

If `cv2.imread()` returns a numpy array you can use `image.ravel()`, alternatively (for a general data structure) itertools chain would do, add this import statement

```
from itertools import chain
```

and than you can do

```
dataset.append([list(chain(*image),label])
```

to get the image as a flat list or

```
dataset.append([np.fromiter(chain(*image),label])
```

to get a numpy array